Need Excel Macro to duplicate row per "X" marked in column (VBA)
Need a macro that will help me process data where they add an X to mark which group the row belongs to. For example:

The data comes with many more columns but that's just the gist of it. They mark with an X the groups the rows belong to and the group ID is in the header. Would be great if it could copy the header and replace it with the "X". Just need the rows duplicated per group marked in the column.
This needs to be in VBA not SQL. Code:
Sub DuplicateRowsPerCategory()
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim catHeaders() As String

' Set the worksheet where your data is located
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") ' Change "Sheet1" to your sheet name

' Determine the last row with data
lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

' Array to store category headers
ReDim catHeaders(1 To lastRow, 1 To 100) ' Assuming maximum 100 columns

' Loop through each row
For i = 2 To lastRow ' Assuming headers are in row 1
    k = 1
    ' Loop through each column to find categories marked with "X"
    For j = 2 To ws.Cells(i, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        If ws.Cells(i, j).Value = "X" Then
            ' Duplicate the row
            ws.Rows(i).Copy
            ws.Rows(i + k).Insert Shift:=xlDown
            
            ' Store category header for this row
            catHeaders(i + k, k) = ws.Cells(1, j).Value
            
            k = k + 1
        End If
    Next j
    ' Replace "X" with empty in original row
    For j = 2 To ws.Cells(i, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        If ws.Cells(i, j).Value = "X" Then
            ws.Cells(i, j).Value = ""
        End If
    Next j
Next i

' Add category headers as new columns
For i = 1 To lastRow
    For j = 1 To 100
        If catHeaders(i, j) <> "" Then
            ws.Cells(i, ws.Cells(i, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1).Value = catHeaders(i, j)
        End If
    Next j
Next i

' Remove empty columns
For j = ws.Cells(1, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column To 2 Step -1
    If WorksheetFunction.CountA(ws.Columns(j)) = 0 Then
        ws.Columns(j).Delete
    End If
Next j

' Clear clipboard
Application.CutCopyMode = False

MsgBox "Rows duplicated per category successfully!", vbInformation End Sub

It's not doing anything to my code.

Where is your attempt? What problem did you have getting your attempt to work?

Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?.
Please create MD table with online tool Table Generator

VBA Code

Using an array to load and transform data in memory is a more efficient approach.

Microsoft documentation:

Range.Resize property (Excel)


Range.CurrentRegion property (Excel)

Option Explicit

Sub Demo()
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim arrData, arrRes, iR As Long
    Dim RowCnt As Long, ColCnt As Long
    ' load data into array
    arrData = ActiveSheet.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Value
    RowCnt = UBound(arrData)
    ColCnt = UBound(arrData, 2)
    ReDim arrRes(1 To RowCnt * (ColCnt - 3), 1 To 4)
    ' header
    arrRes(1, 1) = "Group": arrRes(1, 2) = arrData(1, ColCnt - 2)
    arrRes(1, 3) = arrData(1, ColCnt - 1): arrRes(1, 4) = arrData(1, ColCnt)
    iR = 1
    ' loop through table
    For i = LBound(arrData) + 1 To UBound(arrData)
        For j = LBound(arrData, 2) To ColCnt - 3
          If UCase(arrData(i, j)) = "X" Then
          ' populate output array
            iR = iR + 1
            arrRes(iR, 1) = arrData(1, j)
            arrRes(iR, 2) = arrData(i, ColCnt - 2)
            arrRes(iR, 3) = arrData(i, ColCnt - 1)
            arrRes(iR, 4) = arrData(i, ColCnt)
          End If
        Next j
    Next i
    Sheets.Add
    ' write output to sheet
    Range("A1").Resize(iR, 4) = arrRes
End Sub




Power Query
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Group 1", type text}, {"Group 2", type text}, {"Group 3", type text}, {"First Name", type text}, {"Last Name", type text}, {"Phone Number", type text}}),
    #"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Changed Type", {"First Name", "Last Name", "Phone Number"}, "Group", "Value"),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Unpivoted Other Columns",{"Value"}),
    #"Reordered Columns" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Removed Columns",{"Group", "First Name", "Last Name", "Phone Number"})
in
    #"Reordered Columns"

